# Stability for the 2d diffusion equation

Tags: finite-difference, numerics, stability, diffusion, cfl

I'm reading [this set of notes](https://www.uni-muenster.de/imperia/md/content/physik_tp/lectures/ws2016-2017/num_methods_i/heat.pdf) on numerical stability of the diffusion equation. I can't seem to derive equation (7.17) from the previous equation. I've tried using $\sin^2(\theta)=\frac{1-\cos(2\theta)}{2}$, I've tried looking for the maximum using the first order optimality conditions.
I'm missing a trick. Any help would be appreciated.

Specifically given

$$
g(k) = 1 - 4\alpha\sin^2(k_x\Delta{x}/2) - 4\beta\sin^2(k_y\Delta{y}/2),\\
   D > 0 \\
 \alpha = D\Delta{t}/\Delta{x}^2 >0\\
 \beta = D\Delta{t}/\Delta{y}^2 >0
$$

We need to show $\alpha + \beta < \frac{1}{2}$ implies $|g|<1$.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems that there is an understandable treatment in Hoffman and Chiang's book:  "Computation Fluid Dynamics Volume 1"

Comment: hint: consider what values $sin^2$ can take.

Comment: Got it - brain was not working yesterday.